# Как проинтегрировать уравнение из переменной?

Tags: python, математика, scipy, sympy

Имеется код интегрирования некоторой функции `f(x)`, но уравнение данной функции высчитывается программой заранее и записывается в переменную `m_1`.

С не отформатированным уравнением (`return (x)**2`) программа справляется хорошо, а вот из переменной (если вставить `return m_1`)  программа не хочет это уравнение принимать.

Подскажите, как можно проинтегрировать уравнение, или возможно есть другой вариант интегрирования таких функций?

```
import sympy as sm
import scipy.integrate as sc
x = sm.Symbol("x")

m_1 = (x)**2
def f(x):
    return (x)**2

i = sc.quad(f, 0,3)

print(i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [integrate(...)](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
In [320]: from sympy import integrate

In [321]: res = integrate(m_1, (x, 0, 3))

In [322]: res
Out[322]: 9

In [323]: type(res)
Out[323]: sympy.core.numbers.Integer

In [324]: res.evalf()
Out[324]: 9.00000000000000

In [326]: float(res)
Out[326]: 9.0
```